# How do I check if args[1] is a mention in discord.js commands?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to check if `agrs[1]` is a member name or not.
The code I'm currently using:

```
const Discord = require ('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client() 

const PREFIX = "!"; 

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('connect as ' + client.user.tag)
    let guild = client.guilds.get('636639114787291137')

})

client.on('message', message =>{
    let agrs = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch (agrs[0]){
        case 'teammate':
            if (!agrs[1]) {
                return message.reply("enter a member after !teammate")
            }
            else {
                message.reply(agrs[1]) 
            }

        break;

    }
})

client.login("xxx")
```

Comment: please work on your code formatting

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Comment: I'd recommend changing your question as stated above. Also, your question was improved but you revised it to an older version. I would recommend accepting question improvements as long as they improve the question. (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58539324/revisions#spacer-f0f7b038-5ec6-4641-b267-31970814dc8c)

Comment: By the way, you have a typo, “`let agrs`”.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
message.mentions.members.first()
```

This returns the first member **mentioned** in the message.

Documentation: [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message), [Mentions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions), [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember), [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection)

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
let guild = client.guilds.get(message.guild);
const user = message.mentions.users.first();
const userID = user.id;

if (guild.member(userID)) {
  console.log("That is a correct mention");
}
```